# What happened to the Sith Star Destroyer that destroyed the planet Kijimi in 'The Rise of Skywalker'?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In the movie *The Rise of Skywalker*, Emperor Palpatine dispatches the *Xyston*-class Star Destroyer *Derriphan* to the planet Kijimi to destroy it, and it does so using its axial superlaser.

I am curious to know if the *Derriphan* had immediately returned to the planet Exegol, participated in the Battle of Exegol, and was destroyed with the other Star Destroyers. If it did not return to Exegol, is it safe to assume that after the Battle of Exegol, it cruised around the galaxy and likely blew up other Resistance planets?

I've been researching Star Wars canon and websites, but I haven't found anything yet that sheds light on what happened to this Star Destroyer.

Comment: I believe most of the remaining First Order forces were handwaved away by 'the Galaxy rose up' which is... utterly meaningless and ridiculous, they are a military power, a milita that can destroy them wouldn't just be sitting around... but hey, that's just like my opinion, man.

Comment: @WraithLeader - The point was that if you take into account all the 'little ships', those outnumber the Final Order 10:1. They just needed a cause they could rally behind or a threat so existential that fighting was the preferred option.

Comment: @Valorum it's also apparent that a few shots from a Y-wing can kill a Xyston, as they apparently don't have shields and moved the reactor flaw from the first deathstar into the laser itself, and made the target 100 meters long instead of just 2 meters wide

Comment: @WraithLeader - With the shields up, the BFG is practically invulnerable.

Comment: It fell down. Went boom.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is apparently available in the official novelization of The Rise Of Skywalker according to a Youtuber that received an early copy.

According to him, the book states that the ship simply went back to Exegol to rejoin the fleet after its deed and it got destroyed like the rest.

Answer (score 5):

**It returned to Exegol.**

> Captain Chesille Sabrond stood on the bridge of the Derriphan, looking
> through the viewport at the rest of the Sith Fleet.
>
> They held formation slightly above everyone else, as the only
> Destroyer to have already made the climb. Allegiant General Pryde had
> tasked her crew with observing the ascension and reporting any
> anomalies.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

**and was destroyed with the rest of the Final Order fleet.**

> Framed by the Steadfast’s viewport window, **the designated advance Destroyer Derriphan turned into a ball of fire** as a trio of A-wings swooped out of range of the blast they’d created.
>
> Pryde grimaced. There were bound to be casualties, and the Derriphan had been commanded by a mediocre captain with no real potential—that ship had been designated expendable after all. But he hated for the gnats to claim any sort of victory.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Comment: I'm going to have to read this Expanded Edition because I still have a lot of questions about this movie and the logic (or lack of logic) behind the plot/story line.