# How many Sith Star Destroyers were left at the end of Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

I was just wondering if ***all*** of the Sith Star Destroyers from *The Rise of Skywalker* were destroyed in the Rebel fleet's attack or if there are some that survived, possibly beneath the surface of the planet.

Canon sources preferred, please.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/228255/58193).

Comment: I've voted to close as a dupe. My answer confirms that *all* of the destroyers were on Exegol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108714/discussion-between-old-no-name-and-thelethalcarrot).

Comment: Which part of "*They held formation slightly above everyone else, **as the only Destroyer to have already made the climb. Allegiant General Pryde had tasked her crew with observing the ascension and reporting any anomalies**.*" doesn't answer your question?

Comment: because that doesn't say that some of them may have been under construction inside the planet, or on another part of the planet.

Comment: @Valorum all of it to be fair. Maybe I’m missing something but I don’t see how that answers the question.

Comment: "*“I’m certain of it,” Finn said, scanning the horizon from the viewport. Debris was falling everywhere. **Exegol was going to be a wasteland after this**. Not that it had been paradise to begin with. But all those Star Destroyers were going to smolder for years.*"

Comment: All that it needs for a 10th movie.

Comment: @OldNoName - Can anyone answer whether there were some secret/unfinished (buried) sith star destroyers that didn't appear in the film? No. I doubt you'll find an answer unless you actually go and ask Hidalgo or someone.

Comment: That is what I was taking about

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened to the Sith Star Destroyer that destroyed the planet Kijimi in 'The Rise of Skywalker'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228255/what-happened-to-the-sith-star-destroyer-that-destroyed-the-planet-kijimi-in-th)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they were all destroyed:

> With Palpatine dead the Resistance could not be stopped. The Final Order fleet fell into disarray as **the Resistance systematically destroyed each Star Destroyer.** As the fleet's numbers thinned the crews of the remaining vessels began to abandon ship rather than face inevitable death aboard their doomed warships.
>
> Disabled Star Destroyers fell from the sky, crashing into Exegol. Many pierced the surface completely, causing irreparable damage to the vast subterranean infrastructure that had previously been used by the Sith Eternal to build the fleet.
>
> <sub>[*Battles that Changed the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy), p250</sub>

The same source confirms that all of the Sith Eternal were killed in the battle:

> ##### CASUALTIES
>
> [...]
>
> **SITH ETERNAL:** The resurrected Emperor Palpatine and the entirety of the Sith Eternal cult were wiped out in the battle. Alongside them, General Pryde and the crew of the *Steadfast* all perished.
>
> <sub>[*Battles that Changed the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy), p250</sub>